# Direction of particle's vibration.

Tags: waves

I have seen a question related to the the direction of the vibration when a wave moves. I see there [two opposite picture that](http://www.physics4all.com/questions/contradiction-between-the-direction-of-the-oscillations/) represents  contradictory notion of getting the accurate direction of the vibration. What i think   the displacement  and the  vibration direction will be unique. Is I'm wrong correct me how to get direction of wave and direction of vibration?

Comment: There is no contradiction, they are two different kind of waved. An example of longitudinal wave is a sound wave, and an example of transverse wave is a guitar cord.

Comment: No  i wanted to make a comparison between two Transverse waves.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What i make out of it is that you are getting confused in the direction of vibration of each particle. Am i right?

Comment: yes right you are, direction of particle and direction of wave motion.

Comment: oh, I see, the one at the top is a stationary wave (the peaks and valleys do not move horizontally, the blue one is traveling wave, the peaks (not the particles) move to the right.